# Merging of VMDK files to Single VMDK - Diskname or some other argument is missing

Tags: merge, vmdk

Hi I would like merge vmdk files into one single file. I use 
vmware-vdiskmanager.

I tried used this cmd

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation>vmware-vdiskmanager -r C:\Users
\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64\Windows Server 2008 R
2 x64.vmdk -t 0 singlefile.vmdk
Diskname or some other argument is missing.
VMware Virtual Disk Manager - build 528992.
Usage: vmware-vdiskmanager.exe OPTIONS <disk-name> | <mount-point>
```

I don’t understand this error:      **Diskname or some other argument is missing.**
because I have file Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk in this location.

[image]

EDITED:

I tried this:

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe –r "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk" –t 0 "singlefile.vmdk"
```

and this

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe –r 'C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk' –t 0 'singlefile.vmdk'
```

and last this

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe –r "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk" –t 0 "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64\singlefile.vmdk"
```

But error is same.

Comment: I suggest you put quotes around the file path arguments and try again.

Comment: Yes Quotes and full path names, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have one mistake in your syntax.

**Try this:**

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe –r "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk" –t 0 singlefile.vmdk
```

**Or you can create the new disk in a directory:**

```
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe –r "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk" –t 0 "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\singlefile.vmdk"
```

But you have to run these commands in a console with administration rights.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware
>   Workstation\vmware-vdiskmanager.exe" -r
>   "C:\Users\Mike\Documents\Virtual Machines\Windows Server 2008 R2
>   x64\Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.vmdk" -t 0 singlefile.vmdk

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Unfortunately @Hadi's solution did not solve my issue. What did was `cd`ing to the directory where the `vmdk`s were, and running the command from there.

I think the cause is that `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` doesn't work with spaces in paths, possibly due to a problem with it's argument parser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using **Command Prompt** instead of PowerShell.
In both cases, with administrator privileges.
With PowerShell I kept getting that error, with the Prompt it worked right away.

I ran the command from `C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation` as per instructions, furthermore, I had no problems with the filename and path which contained spaces.

Hope to be of help to someone.